# android not detect file send by DDMS

Tags: android, ddms

i do not understand why only by emulator, i can't read files that i have into my SD card directory (send it by DDMS). This is how i create a directory:

```
public static boolean makeDirectory(Context context){
    boolean make= true;
    String sp = Utility.getDirectory();

    File dirp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), sp);        

    if (!dirp.exists()) {
        if (!dirp.mkdirs()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return make;
}   

public static String getDirectory(){
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/EchoDrive/";
}
```

this is how i read my directory:

```
File directory = new File(Utility.getDirectory()); 
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

why from Android emulator array files is always null? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the SD card.  Try this code :

sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

Comment: when i have to use it?

Comment: Use it after creating the directory.